# SQL routine to Generate Powerset values from Data with Parent/Child relationship

Tags: sql, tree, powerset

I have a requirement where users are users are entering individual items into a table with a trigger that creates the valid combination records (ie. Powerset or subsets) in the table. The challenge that I am having is that the records can have a Parent/Child relationship and in those circumstances there are subsets that are not going to be valid in the 2^n set of values.

Here is a simplified example.

DATA:

> ```
>  ID     Item     Parent_ID  
>   1      A        Null  
>   2      B        Null
>   3      C        Null
>   4      D        1
> ```

Desired Output:

> A
>   B
>   C
>   D
>   A,B
>   A,C
>   B,C
>   A,D
>   A,B,C
>   A,B,D
>   A,C,D
>   A,B,C,D

Before I realized that the data would have Parent/Child relationships I was going to use the following code:

```
WITH ctePowerset(Combo) AS (SELECT     RTRIM(CONVERT(VarChar(30), Item_ID)) AS Item_ID
                                                                        FROM         dbo.tblPowerset
                                                                        UNION ALL
                                                                        SELECT     CONVERT(Varchar(30), RTRIM(CONVERT(varchar(30), TL.Item_ID)) + ',' + cte.Combo) AS combo
                                                                        FROM         dbo.tblPowerset AS TL INNER JOIN
                                                                                              ctePowerset AS cte ON CONVERT(varchar(30), TL.Item_ID) <> cte.Combo AND TL.Item_ID < LEFT(cte.Combo, CHARINDEX(',', 
                                                                                              cte.Combo + ',') - 1))
SELECT     Combo
 FROM         ctePowerset AS ctePowerset_1
```

But with this common table expression I get all 15 possible combinations rather than only the 12 valid/desired ones.

I am a novice SQL programmer and I have been trying to figure out a solution of over a week with absolutely no success. Any help would be greatly appreciated (Even if it is to tell me that this is an impossible task).
Hopefully I have provided enough information and someone can assist me.